# Using yq in Front Matter .md files with conditional operations

Tags: yq, yaml-front-matter

I have Front Matter files like this:

```
---
title: BMW i320 M3 150HP Petrol 2020
category: sportscar
color: metal
---

MD content Starts Here
Lorem ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsun
Lorem ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsun
```

Using **kislyuk's python-yq**, I managed to accomplish my goal using following command:

```
yq -i -y '
    if (.category=="sportscar") and (.title | contains(" Petrol")) then
        .engine = "fuel"
      elif (.category=="sportscar") and (.title | contains(" Gasoline")) then
        .engine = "fuel"
      elif (.category=="sportscar") and (.title | contains(" Diesel")) then
        .engine = "fuel"
      elif (.category=="sportscar") and (.title | contains(" Ethanol")) then
        .engine = "fuel" 
      elif (.category=="sportscar") and (.title | contains(" Aviation Gas")) then
        .engine = "fuel"
      else
        .engine = "electric"
      end' *
```

**THIS WORKS ONLY IF MD FILE HAVE NO CONTENT BELLOW ---**
And I cant lose this content.

So I went to ***mikefarah***'s yq version. Because of that *--front-matter=process* option.

Actually this can process the md files, without mess with the content part
But this yq version dont work with If Elif Else approach.

So it throws me this error:

```
Error: parsing expression: Lexer error: could not match text starting at 1:6 failing at 1:8.
    unmatched text: "if"
```

How can i make this conditional approach, without lose the content part of MD Files?
I have more than 2000 files to manage.... +80%  has content bellow ---

I need this final scenario:

```
---
title: BMW i320 M3 150HP Petrol 2020
category: sportscar
color: metal
engine: fuel
---

MD content Starts Here
Lorem ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsun
Lorem ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsun
```

Comment: @they help me here?

Comment: Did the answer below help you at all?

Answer (score 1):

[mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) does not have an explicit `if-then-else` construct available as part of its DSL, but it can be emulated using cascading [`with(..)` conditions](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/usage/tips-and-tricks#logic-without-if-elif-else) as below

```
yq -f process '(
  with(select(.category=="sportscar" and .title |
    (contains("Petrol") or contains("Diesel") or contains("Ethanol") or contains("Aviation Gas")));
    .engine = "fuel"
  ) |
  with(select(.category=="sportscar" and .title |
    ((contains("Petrol") or contains("Diesel") or contains("Ethanol") or contains("Aviation Gas")) | not));
    .engine = "electric"
  )
)' yaml
```

Tested on version `4.24.2` (current latest release). Add the in-place replacement flag (`-i`) once you verify the contents are processed as expected in a few files.